# Combine Identical nested Attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a quote form that allows you to add items. My `Quote` class `accepts_nested_attributes_for :items`. The user has the ability to search for items and if the user adds the same item again to their quote, the quote then contains two duplicate items.

My `Item` model has an attribute `quantity`. I am trying to combine the `quantity` values if an item exists already in the cart and then reject that new item. I thought about trying something like this but I'm not entirely sure how to properly reference the exact instance of the item and also prevent selecting the same item which would prevent a save every time.

```
class Quote
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :items, allow_destroy: true, :reject_if => :combine_and_reject?

    def combine_and_reject?
        item = self.quote.items.select{|i| i.name == self.name}.first
        if item
            item.quantity = item.quantity + self.quantity
            return true
        else
            return false
        end
    end
end
```

Here are my item fields.

```
create_table "items", options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text "name"
    t.decimal "price", precision: 12, scale: 2, default: "0.0"
    t.integer "quantity"
    t.text "description"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer "quote_id"
    t.index ["quote_id"], name: "fk_rails_e674778822"
end
```

Comment: Can't the name of the `item` be changed? and can you please share the schema.rb?

Comment: It can be. If it is, then I need those quantities to combine. I've updated the question with the items schema. @Rthi

Comment: Tour schema shows that Item doesn't have an ID, why is that? Also, seems like Item is a child of Quote but what is the schema of the items which a user can search for? I assume there is another table of items which are not bound to Quote and which user can search through to add to a cart, is it correct?